# How can I avoid ignored files when I checkout a subtree branch?

Tags: git, gitignore, git-checkout, git-subtree

I have a project with the following structure:

```
.
├── development
│   └── ignoredfile
├── .gitignore
└── master
    └── masterfile
```

The content of .gitignore file is `development/ignoredfile`

Then I create a git repository and a development branch:

```
git init .
git checkout -b development
git add .
git commit -m "First commit"
```

After that I create a subtree with the command:

```
git subtree split --prefix master --annotate="(master) " -b master
```

When I checkout to master:

```
git checkout master
```

I get

```
.
├── development
│   └── ignoredfile
└── masterfile
```

My question is how can I avoid the ignored files when I checkout to master? How can I get only:

```
.
└── masterfile
```